# Скрывать функции, блоки в редакторе кода Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Подскажите как скрывать функции, блоки  в редакторе кода Google Sheets . Уже под 1000 строк кода. Копаться в большой портянке очень неудобно. Может в настройках что подкрутить, или расширение какое есть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/google-apps-script-ide/
В новом ИДЕ можно скрывать блоки кода
или разделяйте код на разные файлы

Comment: Спасибо. Не знаю как на этом форуме, пометить Ваше сообщение как ответ меня устраивающий и избаляющий от страданий. Пользовался старой версией, потому что в ней удобно публиковать скрипты в Интернете для связи с сайтами. В новой версии кнопки Опубликовать не нашел пока. Но благодаря Вашей ссылки буду разбираться. И расширение с темной темой видимо заново нужно устанвливать.

Comment: @YuriCoder Галочку слева нажать ;)